# Android keyguard lock disabled automatically

Tags: android, keyguardlock

I am working on an application that will replace the default lock screen (swipe to unlock) for android devices. I have successfully done this by disabling the keyguard manager and showing my activity using broadcast reciever for screen OFF and screen ON intent. Now, the problem is when I set the default screen lock again for any reason then my application would not disable the keyguard unless I force close it and launch it again. Any help would be appreciated.